# How to convert a string with mathematical operators to number (integer or float)

Tags: c, math, numbers, equals

I have a problem with converting a string like "(5+2)*3" to be able to evaluate to be 21.

Here is my code:

```
char inp[10];
printf("Write it: ");
scanf("%s", inp);
printf("Okay, computing!\n");
printf("INPUT: %s \n", inp);
printf("It's %d \n", (int)inp);
```

I would like to get a number at the end.
This code is working:

```
printf("19+31 is '''%d'''", 19+31);
```

And i need to use the second argument - the 19+31 - to be my input.

The first code outputs this:

```
Write it: 4+4                                                                                
Okay, computing!                                                                             
INPUT: 4+4                                                                                   
It's 329554704
```

Comment: There's no way to compute expressions in strings, neither at compile-time or run-time. If you want to read and evaluate expressions you have to write a *parser* to parse the input, and an *evaluator* or *interpreter* which process the parsed input.

Comment: I only want to convert the numbers in strings, and execute it with the mathematical operators.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - not in the C language. OP should choose an interpreted language which allows this kind of operations - for example python with its eval math method

Comment: @PingvinChannel you cant in C and (judging from the question) I do not think that you are experienced enough to write the parser and evaluator (it is complex programming task)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this directly.  C has no built-in way to evaluate expressions which are entered (as an arbitrary string) at run time.  But that's exactly what you need here.

Writing an expression evaluator is a very interesting exercise -- but probably not for your first (or even second) C program.

Here is a tiny example to give you a feel for it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int eval(char *);

int main()
{
    char expr[100];
    int x;
    printf("Type an expression:\n");
    fgets(expr, sizeof(expr), stdin);
    x = eval(expr);
    printf("Answer: %d\n", x);
}

int eval(char *str)
{
    char *p;
    int lhs, rhs;
    char op;
    int r = 0;
    lhs = strtol(str, &p, 10);
    while(*p == ' ') p++;
    op = *p++;
    rhs = strtol(p, &p, 10);
    switch(op) {
        case '+': r = lhs + rhs; break;
        case '-': r = lhs - rhs; break;
        case '*': r = lhs * rhs; break;
        case '/': r = lhs / rhs; break;
    }
    return r;
}
```

This works, but it's terribly limited: it handles only simple two-term expressions a+b, a-b, a*b, and a/b.  (What's worse, there's no obvious way to extend it to handle fully-general expressions with parentheses and more than two terms.  Handling fully-general expressions will require a completely different, more sophisticated approach.)

---

Addendum: Here's a -- didactically challenged -- example of that "more sophisticated approach":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int e0(char *);
int e1(char **);
int e2(char **);
int e3(char **);
void w(char **);
void q();

int main()
{
    char b[100];
    while(fgets(b, sizeof(b), stdin))
        printf("%d\n",e0(b));
}

int e0(char *s)
{
    return e1(&s);
}

int e1(char **s)
{
    int r = e2(s);
    while(1) {
        w(s);
    switch(*(*s)++) {
            case '+': r += e2(s); break;
        case '-': r -= e2(s); break;
        default: (*s)--; return r;
        }
    }
}

int e2(char **s)
{
    int r = e3(s);
    while(1) {
        w(s);
        switch(*(*s)++) {
            case '*': r *= e3(s); break;
            case '/': r /= e3(s); break;
            default: (*s)--; return r;
        }
    }
}

int e3(char **s)
{
    int c;
    w(s);
    c = *(*s)++;
    if(isdigit(c)) {
        c -= '0';
        while(isdigit(**s)) c = 10 *c + *(*s)++ - '0';
        return c;
    } else if(c == '-') {
        return -e3(s);
    } else if(c == '(') {
        int r = e1(s);
        w(s);
        if(*(*s)++ != ')') {
            q();
            (*s)--;
        }
        return r;
    } else {
        q();
        return 0;
    }
}

void w(char **s)
{
    while(**s == ' ' || **s == '\t' || **s == '\n') (*s)++;
}

void q()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "?\n");
}
```

This works, and you're welcome to compile it and play with it.  It's an unsophisticated implementation of a [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) for simple expressions involving integers, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, parentheses, and unary `-`.  It can handle things like `1+2*3`, `(1+2)*3`, and `1----2----3`.  (That last example is legal under this parser, though not in C.)

I called it "didactically challenged" because it's not designed for teaching -- it's a cleanup of an ill-inspired attempt I made many years ago to squeeze the code down to a bare minimum, resulting in something that was practically an [IOCCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest) entry.

Comment: Thank you! I really-really appreciate your huge help! :)